# Заменить подстрок в строке после определенной подстроки

Tags: c++, строки, подстрока

Суть: есть обычная строка `std::string`, в которой находится произвольной длины список чисел через запятую (например: `"1,2,32454,0,67,123"`). Нужно, чтобы после нуля, все последующие числа так же заменялись на 0 (т.е. `"1,2,32454,0,0,0"`).

Как это можно сделать? Может, в boost-е есть что-то необходимое?

Comment: [да, регулярные выражения в boost-е тоже имеются](https://habr.com/ru/post/64226/)

Comment: А строка именно такая? Цифры и запятые?

Comment: Мне только кажется, что эта задача должна как-то решаться в одну строку с использованием ranges? Разделение на куски, transform, собирание назад? Я уже задавал вопросы по ranges, но так с ними и не смог разобраться как следует, так что **объявляю премию в 200 реп** тому, что покажет и *внятно пояснит словами*, как это сделать через `ranges`. Да, пока конкурс объявить не могу, но уже обещаю :) Но только именно за ranges!!

Comment: @Mikhailo Если мой ответ — то, что вас интересует, то я допишу пояснения. Если нет — оставлю как есть. Просто не уверен, что нельзя сделать короче и красивее, к тому же у меня VC++2019, в нем нет `join_with` (было бы красивее, но не могу проверить).

Comment: @Harry Ну, мне представлялось это как-то покороче :), но раз ничего другого нет... Опишите, как вы пришли к такому решению.

Comment: @Mikhailo Читайте обновленный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так устроит?

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    string ins{"1,2,32454,0,67,123"}, s;

    bool z = false;
    ranges::copy(views::join(split_view(ins,","sv) |
                 views::transform([&z](auto q) {
                     string s(q.begin(),q.end());
                     if (z || stoi(s)==0) { z = true; return "0,"s; }
                     else return s+","; })),
                 back_inserter(s));
    s.pop_back();

    cout << s;
}
```

Чисто теоретически (не могу у себя проверить) должно при поддержке C++23 работать

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    string ins{"1,2,32454,0,67,123"}, s;

    bool z = false;
    ranges::copy(views::join_with(split_view(ins,","sv) |
                 views::transform([&z](auto q) {
                     string s(q.begin(),q.end());
                     if (z || stoi(s)==0) { z = true; return "0"s; }
                     else return s; }),","),
                 back_inserter(s));
    cout << s;
}
```

но тут я никакой гарантии не даю...

@D4rki, это, конечно, из пушки по воробьям. Проще каким-нибудь `strtok`'ом поделить строку на части и сшить наново с учетом нолей...

**Update 1**

Как я к этому пришел... Глобальное решение — делим строку по запятым, встретив 0, запоминаем, дальше все заменяем на 0, и собираем строку вновь.

Итак, деление. Это делается с помощью

```
split_view(ins,","sv)
```

`sv` — потому что функция требует `string_view`, без этого не понимает, что надо, и не работает.

Итак, мы получили набор `string_view`, представляющих числа. Дальше мы преобразуем их в строки, которые либо совпадают с исходными, либо нули (после обнаружения первого нуля). Сначала я думал сделать на выходе числа, но потом решил, что особого смысла в двойном преобразовании нет. Хотя строку все равно пришлось строить из `string_view` — чтобы получить целочисленное значение. Почему не сравнение со строкой? Да чтоб не упустить случай `000`, например.

Это преобразование выполняется с помощью `transform` и лямбда-функции, которая захватывает переменную `z` — флаг, был ли уже нуль или нет:

```
[&z](auto q) {
    string s(q.begin(),q.end());
    if (z || stoi(s)==0) { 
        z = true;           // Выставляем флаг.
        return "0,"s;       // Теперь нули 
    } 
    else return s+","; 
}                           // Строка, что и была
```

Можно сэкономить и переписать, чтоб конвертирования в строку при `z == true` не было вовсе. Хотите — займитесь... Запятые добавил, потому что надо же разделитель, а готовой функции копирования с разделителем не нашел.

Далее собираем все это в одну последовательность с помощью `views::join()`, которую легко собрать в одну строку с помощью `ranges::copy()`, который копирует последовательность с использованием в качестве целевого итератора `back_inserter(s)`, где `s` — целевая строка.

Последний штрих — удаление последней запятой `s.pop_back();`. Всё.

Если использовать `join_with()`, то вроде бы можно просто указать запятую как разделитель, но это я проверить у себя не смог, не реализовано это в VC++2019.

**Update 2**

Но если бы это было реально нужно мне, я бы написал что-то вроде

```
string trans(const string& in)
{
    size_t pos = in.npos;
    if (in.starts_with("0,")) pos = 0;
    if (pos == in.npos) pos = in.find(",0,");
    if (pos == in.npos) return in;
    if (pos) ++pos;
    size_t commas = count(in.begin()+pos,in.end(),',');
    string res = in.substr(0,pos);
    for(int i = 0; i <= commas; res += i++ == commas ? "0" : "0,");
    return res;
}
```

и не мучился :)